# How to manipulate html with mutation observer

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers, mutation

What i am trying to do is observe the generation of a page (inside an iframe, but it does not seem to matter) using mutation observer and modify it on the fly.

I was able to modify the css without problem but i can't seem to be able to change html code, here is a sample code:

```js
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver (mutationHandler);
var observerConfig = {childList: true, subtree: true};
mutationObserver.observe(document, observerConfig);

function mutationHandler(mutationRecords) {
    mutationRecords.forEach ( function (mutation) {
        var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
        if (newNodes.length > 0) {
            $(newNodes).each(function() {
                var $node = $(this);
                if ($node.is('div')) {
                    var code = $node.html();
                    $node.html(code); // HERE IS THE TEST LINE !!!!
                }      
            });
        }
    });
}
```

So i placed a simple test line to see how it behave and by simply doing that -- getting the html code from the div and then putting it back as is -- part of the page will just not be generated (almost all of it).

I am at an impasse as to why and what cause this, i am obviously missing something, getting the html using `var code = $node.html();` make something that can not be used back directly.

Comment: Your changes will recursively trigger the observer infinitely thus it'll hang the page. Also what was that about iframes? MutationObserver attached in top document won't be able to listen to changes in an iframe document because it's a different document.

Comment: The scrip is injected in the iframe and does nothing on in the top document. Thanks for the recursive warning, i really didn't thing about that.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to not use jQuery in this situation. The listener for a MutationObserver will be called a *lot*. It should be as fast as possible, doing as little as possible. The way you are using jQuery is causing significant additional work for every single node. That work would be significantly less if this was, trivially, written in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: The problem was the approach, i don't know why i wanted to use `.html()` when i was already using jQuery, so i just continued using jQuery to modify the code, by removing nodes, modifying attributes, etc.. All the good stuff jQuery makes really simple.